# Keep redirect URL after redirecting in destination server reverse proxy

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite, redirect, proxypass

I use Apache as reverse proxy for email web access. Proxy works fine when I connect to login page. I see url email-test.example.com. Unfortunately after login in email server is redirect back to email.example.com(I cant change in email server). So it disconnect me because I need access through proxy server.How can I keep url email-test.example.com ? I suppose I need use mod Rewrite, but I have absolutely no idea how to use it. Thank you

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName email-test.example.com
    Redirect / https://email-test.example.com

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName email-test.example.com
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/access_email.log combined
    ProxyPass / http://email.example.com/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://email.example.com/
    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/localhost.key
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/localhost.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: From [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreverse): To rewrite HTML content to match the proxy, you must load and enable [mod_proxy_html](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy_html.html).

Comment: I installed mod_proxy_html and add these two lines: 
ProxyHTMLEnable On
ProxyHTMLURLMap / https://email-test.domain.com 

And nothing change. What is wrong ?

Comment: you need to examine the exact method way you get the internal domain back in the url, if it is a redirection, proxypassreverse is the method, and maybe something changes that you haven't specified in your proxypassreverse. If it is inside html content then you need to follow Gerald advice. But first, findout which is the exact case.

Comment: OK it is for iNote Domino server. Any suggestions ?

Comment: OK I ask differently. How I can keep URL adress when I connect with 1nd reverse proxy server to 2nd reverse proxy server and on 2nd one is redirect to different adress ?